# How can I get VS Code to consider dynamic styles as valid CSS?

Tags: css, vs-code

I'm building a Lightning Web Component with dynamic styles in VS Code. Each time I do, I get warnings and errors about empty rulesets and expected braces and selectors.

```html
<html-element style={dynamicVariable}></html-element>
```

[image]

I understand that I can get rid of these by turning off CSS validation in VS Code's settings, but is there a way to get these types of instances to validate while still getting valid warnings in other cases?

Comment: It would help if you showed the problem code so the community can advise you best.

Comment: Thanks, @PhilW, I've added an example of the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off HTML validate styles in setting in vs code

Open Vs Code --> File --> Prefrences --> Settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For most people who arrive at this question, @Shivangi's answer provides a helpful way to avoid this type of error while working in LWC.

However, @Chuck specifically asked:

> I understand that I can get rid of these by turning off CSS validation
> in VS Code's settings, but is there a way to get these types of
> instances to validate while still getting valid warnings in other
> cases?

The answer is no -- unfortunately this is VS Code's native language support and not ESLint, which can be disabled line-by-line. As such, it can only be enabled and disabled at the per-workspace or per-user level.